# Not all duplicants are getting their "downtime"

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have the default colony schedule for all duplicants which gives two time slots to "downtime", but some of the duplicants are not getting the "downtime" +1 buff. In fact, only 2 of my 8 duplicants are getting the buff.

Why is this, and how can I get the buff for all 8 duplicants?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think they need somewhere to hang out. Have you built a water cooler or similar.

Comment: @DavidYell No, but the water cooler requires a "recreational building" to have its effect, or so I interpret the message, and recreational buildings are late game stuff. I am only on cycle 20 or so.

Comment: @DavidYell Also, I have 2 other dupes getting the buff, so somehow it is just happening for those 2.

Comment: Perhaps they are interacting with each other. The expressive update brings lots of interaction buffs.